# Arno Pro and unicode-math

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

My usual method of loading fonts for xelatex gives unsatisfactory results when I choose Arno Pro as main text font and Cambria Math as math font, in particular,  inline math symbols are larger then surrounding text. Here is MWE and result of its compilation with xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi>0
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{Arno Pro}
    \usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\begin{document}
If we assume that the radius of the waist at the focus of the 
laser pulse is $a=50\,\mu\textnormal{m}$, and its length is 
$L=1\,\textnormal{cm}$, the electron density is estimated at 
the level of $n_{e} = 1.6{\times}10^{19}\,\textnormal{cm}^{-3}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to correct this issue?

Comment: `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria Math}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I forgot about this option.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\setmathfont` can receive the same font loading options as `\setmainfont` and similar commands, so one among

```
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=<factor>]{Cambria Math}
```

will do. Which one depends on the main font and its features.